# JAVAFX - How can i add a button at a certain position when pressing another button?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to javafx so i need a bit of help.
I have 2 buttons in a VBox and i would like to add another button between these two buttons using only java code, how can this be done?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the VBox.getChildren().Add() method.

```
vbox.getChildren().add(1, button);
```

The first parameter allows you to insert the button at a certain index, if you want the button to be between the first and second element, simply insert at index 1.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can already have the button in place but not visible:

```
button2.setVisible( false );
button2.setManaged( false );
```

In FMXL, it would be:

```
<Button fx:id="button2" visible="false" managed="false" />
```

The setManaged method will prevent the layout from making space for the button.

Then when you want the button to be revealed you do the following:

```
button2.setManaged( true );
button2.setVisible( true );
```